# Replace string in a file on remote servers

Tags: powershell

I wrote a script which will replace string in a file on local system.

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\connectionFailure.properties) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "connectionRetry=false", "connectionRetry=true" } | Set-Content c:\temp\connectionFailure.properties
```

Can someone help me, I need this command to run on multiple server & result should store in a file.

Comment: Can we actually see the source code of your script?

Comment: (Get-Content c:\temp\connectionFailure.properties) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "connectionRetry=false", "connectionRetry=true" } | Set-Content c:\temp\connectionFailure.properties

Comment: There's lots of possibilities to do that. working with unc path like `\\server02\c$\file.properties` and then loop over them with `foreach-object`. working with `invoke-command` or `pssession`, working with `new-psdrive`, working with `psexec`. I'd suggest you google some of these keywords and try it for yourself, if you then have a more specific error, you can come back to us.